# How to show all values at datetime axis in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to show all days at the X axis in this case? Even if i force the minTickInterval to one day highcharts dont show all days.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NR8vG/)

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {type: "column", inverted: true,
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            pointRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) in xAxis:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 1
}
```

Updated your jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/NR8vG/1/

Answer (score 10):

Datetime axes are based on milliseconds, so an interval of one hour is: 3600 * 1000.

The solution above does not work in charts of type: area.

So if your xAxis is in days you could use:

```
chart: {
    type: 'area'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
}
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one since it only shows the days you need excluding the time.